# MinGW gcc missing zlib1.dll

Tags: dll, gcc, mingw

Whenever I try to compile a C file using MinGW's gcc, it gives the error that zlib.dll is missing. Is there any reliable way to get zlib.dll or to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it directly from [zlib website](http://www.zlib.net). There's a link pointing to Windows prebuilt version: http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll.

Comment: Where do I place them?

Comment: @op1ekun if only your app will use this library, you should put it inside the application's directory. Read more on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you install mingw C++ tools, you also need to install mingw32-base. Here's a pic:
[image]

Comment: Yes, either that or just install `zlib` package